# Downloading yfcc100m from aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dataset, s3cmd

I am trying to download a dataset hosted in AWS. 
I am trying to use `s3cmd` and configured it with my access key and secret key.
I can list the the files in the bucket properly using:

```
s3cmd ls s3://yahoo-webscope/I3set13/
```

I used `get` to download the dataset:

```
s3cmd get --recursive s3://yahoo-webscope/I3set13/
```

But the following error is shown:

```
ERROR: S3 error: 403 (Forbidden)
```

A few solutions I found suggested to change the bucket policy, but I can't change it because I am not the owner.

Please let me know the reason behind the problem and how I can solve it.

Comment: Seems like your access/secret key has only `ListObjects` permission and does not have a `GetObject` persmission in the bucket policy. You'll need to update the bucket policy.

Comment: That is the problem. I don't have access to that bucket's policy. That bucket is hosted by someone else. Also I am new to aws. If I misunderstood what you said please provide me a link or some details. Thanks.

Comment: You NEED to have access to the bucket policy OR just tell your host to do it for you.

Comment: @KhalidT. please consider whether perhaps this might be one of the **public** data sets available on S3.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Yes, but even with AWS Public Datasets hosted in S3, one should still be able to download the data (as mentioned here: https://aws.amazon.com/public-datasets/). Maybe the OP needs to clarify more in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://multimediacommons.wordpress.com/yfcc100m-core-dataset/, although the dataset is hosted in an S3 bucket, access to it is restricted, so you need to [submit a request](http://webscope.sandbox.yahoo.com/catalog.php?datatype=i&did=67) and follow further email instructions for access:

> **Getting the YFCC100M**: The dataset can be requested at [Yahoo Webscope](http://webscope.sandbox.yahoo.com/catalog.php?datatype=i&did=67). You will need to create a Yahoo account if you do not have one already, and once logged in you will find it straightforward to submit the request for the YFCC100M. Webscope will ask you to tell them what your plans are with the dataset, which helps them justify the existence of their academic outreach program and allows them to keep offering datasets in the future. Unlike other datasets available at Webscope, the YFCC100M does not require you to be a student or faculty at an accredited university, so you will be automatically approved.

Comment: I requested for the dataset as it is said in the answer. But the thing I did wrong was using access key of another account. The access key have to be from the same account as the one provided when requesting the dataset from yahoo-webscope.

Comment: "The access key have to be from the same account as the one provided when requesting the dataset from yahoo-webscope."
@rakinhaider did you mean the access key have to be from the same Email address as the one provided when requesting the dataset???
Because one can not access Amazon AWS with his Yahoo account.
Or did i miss something?

Comment: Yes, I meant you have to register in Amazon AWS with the same email address as the one with which you have requested the dataset.